# How to perform left join in Hibernate Query Language (HQL)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

Need to be retrieve records from two tables

Table1:**KFT_M_CUSTOMER_CART_LIST**

Table2:**KFT_STATIC_DETAILS**

I tried this **SQL** query it's working in SQLserver

but this query not working in **HQL**

how to write in HQL query

```
SELECT      isnull(S1.VALUE,'') AS PRINT_MEDIUM , 
            isnull(S2.VALUE,'') AS PRINT_QUALITY , 
            isnull(S3.VALUE,'') AS PRINT_SIZE,
            isnull(S4.VALUE,'') AS NO_OF_PRINTS

            from KFT_M_CUSTOMER_CART_LIST M

            LEFT JOIN [KFT_STATIC_DETAILS] S1 ON S1.MASTER_ID=100 AND S1.DETAIL_ID=M.PRINT_MEDIUM
            LEFT JOIN [KFT_STATIC_DETAILS] S2 ON S2.MASTER_ID=200 AND S2.DETAIL_ID=M.PRINT_QUALITY
            LEFT JOIN [KFT_STATIC_DETAILS] S3 ON S3.MASTER_ID=300 AND S3.DETAIL_ID=M.PRINT_SIZE
            LEFT JOIN [KFT_STATIC_DETAILS] S4 ON S4.MASTER_ID=500 AND S4.DETAIL_ID=M.NO_OF_PRINTS
```

Entity class1:KftStaticDetail

```
    @Column(name="MASTER_ID")   
int masterId;

@Id
@Column(name="DETAIL_ID")
int detailId;

@Column(name="VALUE")
String value;

@Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
String description;

@Column(name="ACTIVE")
String active;
```

Entity class 2:KftCartItem

```
@Column(name="PRINT_MEDIUM")
private String printMedium;

@Column(name="PRINT_QUALITY")
private String printQuality;

@Column(name="PRINT_SIZE")
private String printSize;

@Column(name="NO_OF_PRINTS")
private int numberOfPrints;
```

Comment: Provide your entity classes as well.

Comment: I updated the entity class